# How to avoid subsequent calls in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have created a WCF service.These services are used for different clients.Each client is sending a request simultaneously.

I want to set each request to allow for 5 seconds delay to hit my service for a different client.

Currently, client issues subsequent calls to my service method.

How can I allow access to my service with 5 seconds different in my WCF service?

Comment: So you want to rate-limit clients to only do a single request in 5 seconds?

Comment: yes.each client i want to allow 5seconds difference to hit my method.

Comment: What do you want to happen on the client side if they send requests faster?

Comment: yes.they sending multiple request simultaneously within seconds.

Comment: So what do you **want** to happen to them, when they send more than you want to receive? Should they wait? Get an error?